# Generating the whole sigma algebra with two independent sigma algebras

Tags: probability-theory, causality

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathsf P)$ be a probability space. Let $\mathcal B\subset\Omega$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal A$. Does there always exist a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal C$ of $\mathcal A$ such that $\mathcal B$ is independent of $\mathcal C$ and such that $\sigma(\mathcal B\cup\mathcal C)=\mathcal A$ ?

This question is motivated by the Definition of causal graphs, where a random variable $X$ is said to "cause" another random variable $Y$ if there exists a measurable function $f$ and a random variable $E$ independent of $X$ such that $Y = f(X, E)$. I was wondering if any two random variables always "cause" each other.

Comment: A weaker converse of the original question holds: Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are real-valued, there exist random variables $X',Y',E$ on another probability space such that (1) $X'$ and $E$ are independent, (2) $Y'=f(X',E)$ for some Borel-measurable function $f$, and (3) $(X',Y')$ has the same distribution as $(X,Y)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee That is highly interesting: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: You may refer to Proposition 4.1 of *Elements of Causal Inference* by Peters *et al.*, but the proof is actually very simple if we ignore some technicality issue about measurability: Let $X' \perp\hspace{-0.5em}\perp E$ be such that $X'\sim X$ and $E\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$. Then consider the conditional CDF $F_{Y\mid X=x}(y)=\mathbf{P}(Y\leq y\mid X=x)$ and then define $f(x, e)=F_{Y\mid X=x}^{-1}(e)$. Using [inversion sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), it is easy to check that $Y':=f(X',E)$ satisfies $Y'\sim Y$.

Comment: In other words, we first (1) simulate the distribution of $X$, and then (2) simulate the conditional distributions $(Y\mid X=x)$ for any $x$ using the same "noise" $E\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$. Then their composition has the distribution identical to that of $Y$.

Comment: @SangchulLee that is very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is *no*: As a simple counter-example, consider

$$(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathsf P)=(\{1,2,3\}, \mathfrak P(\{1,2,3\}), \text{Uniform}(\{1,2,3\})),$$ where $\mathfrak P(\{1,2,3\})$ denotes the power set of $\{1,2,3\}$ and $ \text{Uniform}(\{1,2,3\})$ denotes the uniform measure over $\{1,2,3\}$.

Choose now $\mathcal B=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2,3\},\Omega\}$. Then any sigma-algebra $\mathcal C$ such that $\sigma(\mathcal B\cup\mathcal C)=\mathcal A$ must contain either $\{2\}$ or $\{1,2\}$ so that $\{2\}\in\sigma(\mathcal B\cup\mathcal C)$. But such a $\mathcal C$ cannot be independent of $\mathcal B$, since we then have either $$\mathsf P(\{1\}\cap\{2\})=0\neq \mathsf P(\{1\})\mathsf P(\{2\})$$ or $$\mathsf P(\{1\}\cap\{1,2\})=\frac 13\neq \frac 29 = \mathsf P(\{1\})\mathsf P(\{1,2\}).$$